# correct package to run json with connect?

Tags: json, gluon

I try to follow the simple connect sample but I got this error class org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl cannot be cast to class javax.json.spi.JsonProvider

Probably problem of version but which one to use
gluon version 4.0.11

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2-b15 </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <classifier>module</classifier>
           
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you check [this pom](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/gluon-connect-file-provider/pom.xml#L69) of the Connect sample?

Comment: thanks I finally find the correct packages and versions that work together. So I am on the next error.

Comment: @CharlesOlivierChampion so whate are the correct packages?